Expressjs session cookie is not being set in react client
For some reason when I login it doesn't set cookie session for client to access content
Expressjs app setup:
const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({
    origin: process.env.ORIGIN,
    credentials: true
}));
app.use(
    cookieSession({
        name: "amtrix-session",
        keys: ["secret"],
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'strict'
    })
);

app.use('/auth', [auth]);
app.use('/user', [user]);

POST /auth/login:
const accessToken = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET!, {
            algorithm: 'HS256',
            allowInsecureKeySizes: true,
            expiresIn: 86400
        });
        (req as any).session.token = accessToken;
        
        res.send({
            banner: user?.banner,
            profile: user?.profile,
            username: user?.username,
            email: user?.email,
            createdAt: user?.createdAt,
            userType: user.userType
        });

When i call GET /user/profile the POST first verifies user token using the authenticate function under. But it always returns status 303 because of token not being provded. Even though during login I set the token to req.session.token
export async function authenticate(req: request, res: response, next: NextFunction) {
    const token = req.session!.token;
    
    if(!token) return res.status(403).send({ message: "No token provided!" });

    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET!, (err: any, decoded: any) => {
        if(err) return catchError(err, res);
        (req as any).userId = decoded.id;
        next();
    });
};

My ReactTS axios to login user:
class Auth {
    private _host = `${process.env.REACT_APP_AMTRIX_API}/auth`;

    private async _callApi(path: string, params: any = {}) {
        const url = `${this._host}${path.startsWith("/") ? path : `/${path}`}`;
        try {
            return await axios.post(url, 
                {
                    params: {
                        ...params
                    }
                },
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    withCredentials: true
                }
            );
        } catch(err: any) {
            throw err;
        };
    };
    public async login(username: string, password: string) {
        try {
            const res = await this._callApi('/login', {
                username,
                password
            });

            UserService.setUser({ ...res.data, email: blurEmail(res.data.email) });

            return res;
        } catch(err) {
            throw err;
        };
    };
};

The weird thing is this all works when i request the api in postman as expected but when it comes to my react client it doesn't work...
I tried to POST /auth/login and I expected it to set jwt to session cookie to req.session.token but its not available when using react app.

Is that your front-end and back-end are running in different port ?

@yuvaraj-m
Yes. Both on local. Client on 3000 and server on 4000. I did try to set up a proxy but that didn't work either.
`
import { createProxyMiddleware } from "http-proxy-middleware";
module.exports = function (app: any) {
app.use(
'/',
createProxyMiddleware({
target: process.env.REACT_APP_AMTRIX_API,
changeOrigin: true,
onProxyReq: (proxyReq, req, res) => {
console.log('Proxying request to:', proxyReq.path);
}
})
);
};
`

Uh not sure what I just did but I fixed it... Welp
